# Dijkstra SDSP Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, segmentation-fault, dijkstra

I'm trying to implement Dijkstra Algorithm for Single Destination Shortest Path using Adjacency List and PQ as Min Heap. The output must show path of all vertices to destination vertex, if path exists, and if yes, the sum of it (shortest), if no, NO PATH.
[Link to entire code](https://replit.com/@AlcorInf/LargeTestyIrc)

Input Format:

- First line is number of vertices, n
- Second line onwards: (Vertices from 1 to n)

  - First column is vertex.
  - After, multiple pairs, <vertex, weight>
- test.txt

```
4
1 2 4 3 5 4 5
4 1 7 3 3
2 1 3 4 10
```

According to GDB, it showed Segmentation fault found at extractMin function.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00401746 in extractMin ()
```

Client.c

Extracting input from the text.txt file and create a directed graph

```
FILE *fptr = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (fptr == NULL) exit(1);

    int n;
    if (fscanf(fptr, "%d", &n) == 1 && n > 0)
    {
        Graph *graph = createGraph(n);
        int c;
        while ((c = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF && c != '\n');
        char *line = NULL;      
        size_t len = 0;        

        while (getline(&line, &len, fptr) > 0)
        {
            char *cur = line;
            int ccs = 0;
            int v1;

            if (sscanf(cur, "%d%n", &v1, &ccs) == 1)
            {
                cur += ccs;
                int v2;
                int w;
                while (sscanf(cur, "%d %d%n", &v2, &w, &ccs) == 2)
                {
                    addEdge(graph, v1, v2, w);
                    cur += ccs;
                }

                fputc('\n', stdout);
            }

        }
        free(line);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            dijkstra(graph, i);
    }
```

Server.c

```
struct MinHeapNode* extractMin(MinHeap* minHeap)
{
    if (isEmpty(minHeap))
        return NULL;
 
    struct MinHeapNode* root = minHeap->array[0];
    struct MinHeapNode* lastNode = minHeap->array[minHeap->size - 1];
    minHeap->array[0] = lastNode;
 
    minHeap->pos[root->v] = minHeap->size-1;
    minHeap->pos[lastNode->v] = 0;
 
    --minHeap->size;
    minHeapify(minHeap, 0);
 
    return root;
}
void dijkstra(Graph* graph, int dest)
{
    int v = graph->vertices;
    int distance[v]; 
    int pathFollow[1000]={0};
    int ind = 0;

    MinHeap* minHeap = createMinHeap(v);
 
    for (int i = 0; i < v; ++i)
    {
        distance[v] = INT_MAX;
        minHeap->array[v] = newMinHeapNode(v, distance[v]);
        minHeap->pos[v] = v;
    }
 
    minHeap->array[dest] = newMinHeapNode(dest, distance[dest]);
    minHeap->pos[dest] = dest;
    distance[dest] = 0;
    decreaseKey(minHeap, dest, distance[dest]);
 
    minHeap->size = v;

    while (!isEmpty(minHeap))
    {
        struct MinHeapNode* minHeapNode = extractMin(minHeap);
        int u = minHeapNode->v;
        AdjListNode* path = graph->array[u].head;
        while (path != NULL)
        {
            int v = path->vertex;
            if (isInMinHeap(minHeap, v) && distance[u] != INT_MAX &&
              path->weight + distance[u] < distance[v])
            {
                distance[v] = distance[u] + path->weight;
                if(pathFollow[ind-1] != u)
                    pathFollow[ind++]=u;
                decreaseKey(minHeap, v, distance[v]);
            }
            path = path->next;
        }
    }
    printArr(distance, v, pathFollow, dest);
}

void printArr(int dist[], int n, int pathFollow[], int dest)
{
    printf("%d", dest+1);
    int j = 0;
    if(dist[n-1]!=0 && dist[n-1] < 100000000) 
    {
        int k = j;
        printf(" %d", pathFollow[k]+1);
        while(pathFollow[j]!=0) 
        {
        printf(" %d", pathFollow[j++]);
        }
        printf(" %d %d\n",n, dist[n-1]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("NO PATH\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try running your code [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/) by adding breakpoints (here's a [tutorial](https://www.cprogramming.com/gdb.html)) in the code and see where the problem is.

Comment: Without us knowing where the code actually faults, what are the inputs to `dijkstra`, we won't be able to help you much.

Comment: I put the entire code link if you didn't see perhaps. Should I show what valgrind showed?

Comment: I tried gdb on VSCode, it threw seg fault in extractMin, I'll edit post

Comment: Edit the post to provide a [mre] in the post. Links may be used for supplemental information, but all information needed to reproduce the problem should be in the question itself. Stack Overflow is not a personal debugging service. It is intended to create a durable repository of questions and answers to aid future readers. But links to external sites break, rendering questions depending on them useless to others. So everything must be in the post. Getting your programs debugged is an incidental benefit, and asking for debugging for a sizable amount of code is something of an abuse.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to all this, I added as much as stack overflow let's me to. I've added as much as I can

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to debug this entire program but here are a few errors:

1. You create

   ```
    Graph *graph = createGraph(n);
   ```

and are then accessing `graph->array[src].head`.

This is a problem since `n` is just the total number of vertices, in your case 4 but when that `addEdge()` is called with something like `4 1 7`, that is a heap-buffer-overflow. You need to account for the `0-indexed` arrays that you create.

2. Another overflow problem, this time of the stack buffer, would be at:

   ```
   int v = graph->vertices;
   int distance[v];
   ```

But then this is referred to as

```
distance[v] = INT_MAX;
```

again not considering the `0-indexed` array. Also, that code seems suspect and should be `distance[i] = INT_MAX` I believe.

Please review your own code for more such errors, especially for array index overflows, use [Address Sanitizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) to check code for memory errors, step through each line of the program, and see if what's expected is indeed happening. You mention the program faults around `extractMin()`. Check if it is accessing the memory it is supposed to access. `SIGSEGV` indicates illegal memory access. Is `struct MinHeapNode* root` pointing to something you allocated? Is `struct MinHeapNode* lastNode` pointing to something you allocated?

Comment: Surely I'll try and update here. It might help people out also